# Can't login to WSO2 IS management console after setup IS as key manager in AM

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am following this doc:

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/configuring-wso2-identity-server-as-a-key-manager/#!

After going through the above doc, i could start up both the AM server and IS server. And I can also login to AM management console.

But I can't login the IS management console. Seems like the `admin` user in IS is not working. And the SCIM APIs also seems not working with the `admin` user anymore...

I notice the below error from IS console log:

```
[2021-01-26 21:45:35,983] [eb202902-8ff7-4e08-a654-72b2341de661] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationAdmin} - System error while Authenticating/Authorizing User : Operation is not supported.
```

Any idea will be helpful! Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to login to AM management console with `admin` credentials?

Comment: @ShanChathusandaJayathilaka Before setting IS as key manager, using `admin` credential, i could login both IS and AM management console. After setting IS as key manager, using the same default credential, i can only login to AM management console...